# Current accepted axiomatic set theory

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Out of the numerous set theories (NBG, ZFC, etc) which is the current accepted one, or is it that each one has built upon the other?

Comment: Could someone explain the down votes???

Comment: Both...........

Comment: See [Zermelo's Axiomatization of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zermelo-set-theory/) and [Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiSetThe)  and [Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/) and [Set Theory: Constructive and Intuitionistic ZF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/index.html).

Comment: No, it rarely happens.  Worse is when you post a answer and it grtsdow

Comment: No, it rarely happens.  Worse is when you post an answer and it gets down voted.  Nothing is learned about what was wrong.  Usenet was much more friendly but has been abandoned for lack of being modern.

Comment: Upvoted to cancel out the downvotes, I don't think this is an unreasonable question for this site.

Comment: @Elliot: You should upvote this question if you think it's a good question. You should *never* vote to "cancel downvotes" (or to cancel upvotes). This is, in essence, saying "someone's opinion doesn't matter".

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean by "accepted." Perhaps you're asking "When people say a theorem has been proven without specifying which set theory (if any) they're working in, what should I assume they're working in 'by default'?" So I'll try answering this.

The vast majority of known mathematical results can be formalized as statements about sets, in the language of ZFC. And furthermore, if a theorem is stated "unconditionally" (i.e., they didn't specify which axioms they used), you can assume they only used axioms of ZFC. Since ZFC and NBG agree on which sentences in the language of ZFC are provable, you can choose to formalize the claim in either. NBG is only really necessary for the occasional claim that needs proper classes to be formalized. Otherwise, there's a general preference to work in ZFC due its simpler ontology (which is convenient when studying models of the respective theories.

Comment: At least for now, ya? In the past, ZFC didn't exist. In the future, who knows what logicians will consider as the accepted foundations? =)